# Redirect the output of python script into a text file

Tags: python

How do we move the output of this script into a text file?

```
 k = raw_input("Enter the keyword:")
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     sys.path.append("./BeautifulSoup")
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

     opener = urllib2.build_opener()
     opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

     for start in range(0,2):
         url = "http://www.google.com.au/search?q="+ k +"&start=" + str(start*10)
         print url
```

Comment: Read ["Reading and Writing Files"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the tutorial.

Comment: @Matthias you wrote it before i could enter my comment :D

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Particularly [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use standard shell redirection:

```
python your_script.py > output_file.ext
```

If you want to write to a file directly from the script without redirecting:

```
with open("output.ext", "w") as stream:
    print >>stream, "text"
```

Comment: no sir..! i ask how to move into text file without executing command prompt..for example   when i execute  script.py   this output directly move to text, dont show in command prompt......

Comment: Thank you..! Its working....!!!

Comment: This doesn't work for me when I run Python.exe from within a CMD file - it creates a blank file and still outputs to the console.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use command line or write():

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('output_file', 'w')
print 'test'
```

That way you can still use `print()`

Comment: I like this solution more, you don't need to do `file.write(...)` every time, although would probably still prefer command line option if it's a one-time-deal

Answer (score 0):

Just call the python script from the terminal like this:

```
python yourfile.py > yourtextfile_with_output.txt
```

For outputting without command line use:

```
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write("your output here")
text_file.close()
```

Comment: 10 seconds too slow :)

Comment: @akalikin LOL, imagine if would have used the same name for the script :-)

Comment: Haha, indeed, but it turns out the OP wanted something different, so I am not too slow this time ;)

Comment: This lines where to insert above my coding....

Comment: The first line above (opening file for write access), the second to write wherever you want and whatever content you want to the file, and the last after the last write.

Comment: one help...! Can You add these lines to above my coding and send it to me?